String to char* conversion in struct or class gives undefined first chars
I want to convert a std::string to a char* with size_t and store the result in a struct. Later I want to retrieve the std::string again. Unfortunately when I retrieve the std::string or char* later on I always get undefined values for the first char* (see minimal example).
What could be the problem here?
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Data {
    Data(std::string string) : m_data(string.data()), m_size(string.size()) {
        std::cout << "String size: " << m_size << std::endl;
        std::cout << "String in constructor: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < m_size; ++j) {
            std::cout << (m_data)[j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    char* m_data;
    size_t m_size;

    static void print_string(Data model_data) {
        std::cout << "String in static function: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < model_data.m_size; ++j) {
            std::cout << model_data.m_data[j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    std::string test_string = "Hello World! The next characters might appear...";
    Data test_data(test_string);
    Data::print_string(test_data);
    std::cout << "String from member: ";
    for (int j = 0; j < test_data.m_size; ++j) {
        std::cout << test_data.m_data[j];
    }        
    return 0;
}

String size: 48
String in constructor: Hello World! The next characters might appear...
String in static function: �~v��� next characters might appear...
String from member: �~v��� next characters might appear...%


You may want to take a look at std::string_view

The issue is that your constructor is making a copy of the string that's passed in. This copy has a limited lifetime and the m_data variable will outlive it once the constructor finishes executing. So it points to invalid data. You need to take a reference to the string.

Almost that entire Data class is simply std::string_view, as pointed out by @TedLyngmo.

From the string_view link: A typical implementation holds only two members: a pointer to constant CharT and a size. -- Your Data class has...char* m_data; size_t m_size;.  So unless you are using something less than C++17, you're basically reinventing the wheel.

I question the purpose of this Data struct. Are you trying to share a string with c or some other language? If you don't have std::string_view could you just keep a std::string or use the string_view from boost: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/boost/utility/string_view.hpp

Your constructor stores a pointer to the data of the string passed in.
Data(std::string string) : m_data(string.data()), ...

but this string is destroyed when the constructor is exited. So you are storing (and then using) a pointer to an object which has been destroyed.
Such a pointer is called a dangling pointer and using a dangling pointer is undefined behaviour.
The only foolproof way around this is for the Data class to own the pointer it is using, for example by allocating memory for the pointer and then copying the string data to the allocated pointer. This means more code has to be added to properly manage this pointer, and the class becomes less lightweight.

In your constructor here:
Data(std::string string) : m_data(string.data()), m_size(string.size())

You make a copy object string whose lifecycle ends at the end of the constructor body. Thus m_data refers to released memory after that and reading it is undefined behavior. You can easily fix that by replacing std::string with a (const) reference to the string object:
Data(const std::string& string)

But that will work only as long as you can ensure lifetime of the passed in string object surpasses the Data object lifetime. If you want to make the object self-sustained and exist without depending on the string object, you have to "own" the underlying char array, e.g. by copying it:
Data(const std::string& string) : m_data{
    std::copy_n(string.data(), string.size(), new char[string.size()]) - string.size()
}, m_size{string.size()}

This, however, also requires you to manage this memory and properly implement special functions, such as copy and move constructors, assignment operators and the destructor (most are deleted in the snippet below to keep the answer concise, but offer a solution without UB)
Data(Data&&) = delete;
Data& operator=(Data&&) = delete;
Data(const Data&) = delete;
Data& operator=(const Data&) = delete;
~Data(){
    delete[] m_data;
}


What is "released memory"? C++ doesn't have this term. In practice above the memory is reused by some another object.

@3CxEZiVlQ From cppreference: "delete expression: Destroys object(s) previously allocated by the new-expression and releases obtained memory area."

Although the cppreference is very useful informational resource, this is just a wiki with subjective information. expr.delete does not use the words "release" or "memory"

@3CxEZiVlQ from what I can see, n4140/basic.life uses term release quite a few times. For relation to deallocation in particular you may consult expr.new section, i.e.: "If the new-expression terminates by throwing an exception, it may release storage by calling a deallocation function"
